# apt installs wrong nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia

Due to a security issue in older nvidia drivers I was tasked to update our system, and now I am running into an issue that the open nvidia drivers keeps getting installed, causing nvidia-smi and cuda to not run properly.

What I did:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove nvidia*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-530
cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
```

Output:

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX Open Kernel Module for x86_64  530.41.03  Release Build  (dvs-builder@U16-T02-35-3)  Thu Mar 16 19:33:35 UTC 2023
GCC version:  gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
```

Note the issue: it says Open Kernel Module, which is not compatible with nvidia-smi

Why does it install the open module, even though that should only happen when I do `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-530-open`?

I did the precisely same thing on another system of ours, where the main difference is that that one is running Ubuntu 18.04:

```
cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  530.41.03  Thu Mar 16 19:48:20 UTC 2023
GCC version:  gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
```

Am I doing something wrong here? How do I fix this?

Comment: Does Ubuntu find a working driver by default?

Comment: You mean ubuntu-drivers autoinstall? Nope, that also resulted in the open kernel driver

Comment: Can you add more details about your graphics card? AFAIK, the newer drivers often support for the older cards.